# Random 500 errors on our gitlab installation

Tags: gitlab

So we installed a clean install of Gitlab on a VPS recently.
We keep getting these weird 500 errors and sometimes we get 502 errors aswell. If you just reload the page it works fine again.

This is what we are getting in the log:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 104ms (ActiveRecord: 11.0ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given -1, expected 0..1)):
    2: .projects-dropdown-container
    3:   .project-dropdown-sidebar.qa-projects-dropdown-sidebar
    4:     %ul
    5:       = nav_link(path: 'dashboard/projects#index') do
    6:         = link_to dashboard_projects_path, class: 'qa-your-projects-link' do
    7:           = _('Your projects')
    8:       = nav_link(path: 'projects#starred') do
  app/helpers/tab_helper.rb:44:in `nav_link'
  app/views/layouts/nav/projects_dropdown/_show.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_layouts_nav_projects_dropdown__show_html_haml__507423338401438640_70116785554280'
  app/views/layouts/nav/_dashboard.html.haml:8:in `block in _app_views_layouts_nav__dashboard_html_haml__3348077098840061580_70116777691560'
  app/helpers/tab_helper.rb:55:in `nav_link'
  app/views/layouts/nav/_dashboard.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_layouts_nav__dashboard_html_haml__3348077098840061580_70116777691560'
  app/views/layouts/header/_default.html.haml:15:in `_app_views_layouts_header__default_html_haml___3435027822084279605_70116622340220'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___580706530271060056_70116596509800'
  app/views/layouts/project.html.haml:14:in `_app_views_layouts_project_html_haml___2694622167901485088_70116784316120'
  app/controllers/projects/merge_requests_controller.rb:22:in `index'
  lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:50:in `with_locale'
  lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:56:in `with_user_locale'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:338:in `set_locale'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:95:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:17:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:11:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:28:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:18:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:10:in `call'
```

Why are we getting these and how do I fix it?

Comment: How is it even possible to send in -1 arguments? I don't get it...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your request? What version of GitLab have you installed? What was the installation method? On which link click you are getting this error?